# VSSCANF Error, Extracting variables from response buffer in c [By Line & By Keyword]

Tags: c

If I extract a single variable from the response buffer both (by line number or keyword) methods are working ok. But if I am trying to extract multiple variables of multiple types like string, int, and float it's not working after a string extraction successfully.
(commented unnessury code)
[godbolt link is here](https://godbolt.org/z/ncYjvo587)

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {

  uint8_t res_buf[2048];

  uint8_t line_counts;

} MODULE_Typedef;  //module buffer

    // validate and get response pointer by line number
uint8_t *MODULE_ATRespGetByLineNumber(MODULE_Typedef *module, uint8_t resp_line) {

uint8_t *resp_buf = module->res_buf;
uint8_t *resp_line_buf = 0;
uint8_t line_num = 1;

if (resp_line > module->line_counts || resp_line <= 0) {

    return 0;
}

for (line_num = 1; line_num <= module->line_counts; line_num++) {
    if (resp_line == line_num) {
        resp_line_buf = resp_buf;

        return resp_line_buf;
    }

    resp_buf += strlen(resp_buf) + 1;
}

return 0;
}
     //parse response by line number
uint16_t MODULE_ATRespParseLine(MODULE_Typedef *module, uint8_t resp_line, const char *resp_expr, ...) {

va_list args;

int resp_args_num = 0;

const char *resp_line_buf = 0;

if ((resp_line_buf = MODULE_ATRespGetByLineNumber(module, resp_line)) == 0) {
    return -1;
}
  // printf("\r\nOK = %s\r\n",resp_line_buf);

va_start(args, resp_expr);

resp_args_num = vsscanf(resp_line_buf, resp_expr, args);

va_end(args);

return resp_args_num;
}
       //validate and get response pointer by keyword
uint8_t *MODULE_ATRespGetByKeyword(MODULE_Typedef *module, uint8_t *keyword) {
char *resp_buf = module->res_buf;
char *resp_line_buf = 0;
uint16_t line_num = 1;

for (line_num = 1; line_num <= module->line_counts; line_num++) {
    if (strstr(resp_buf, keyword)) {
        resp_line_buf = resp_buf;
        
        return resp_line_buf;
    }
    resp_buf += strlen(resp_buf) + 1;
}

return 0;
 }
   //parse response using keyword
uint16_t MODULE_ATRespParse(MODULE_Typedef *module, uint8_t *keyword, uint8_t *resp_expr, ...) 
{

uint16_t resp_args_num = 0;

char *resp_line_buf = MODULE_ATRespGetByKeyword(module, keyword);

va_list args;

if (resp_line_buf) {

    va_start(args, resp_expr);

    resp_args_num = vsscanf(resp_line_buf, resp_expr, args);

    va_end(args);

    return resp_args_num;
  }
}

int main() {

char opr[20] = {"ERROR"}; 
uint8_t gpsv1 = 0,gpsv2 = 0,gpsv3 = 0,gpsv4 = 0,gpsv5 = 0,gpsv6 = 0,gpsv7 = 0,gpsv8 = 0,gpsv9 = 0,gpsv10 = 0,gpsv11=0;
uint8_t mode = -1,format = -1,act = -1;    

MODULE_Typedef resp1 = {
    .res_buf = {"+CREG: 0,2,AIRTEL,45"},
    .line_counts = 1,
};

 printf("\r\n\r\n\r\nbuffer res1 = %s\r\n",resp1.res_buf);

 MODULE_ATRespParse(&resp1,"+CREG:","+CREG: %d, %d, %[^,]s,%d",&mode,&format,opr,&act);

 printf("\r\nmode = %d\nformat = %d\noperator = %s\nnwk = %d\n",mode,format,opr,act);
}
```

my input buffer:

> buffer res1 = +CREG: 0,2,AIRTEL,45

extracted variables from it :

> mode = 0
> format = 2
> operator = AIRTEL
> nwk = 255

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass the correct variable pointer according to format specifiers. If you are using `%d`, It means your argument type shall be `int *`.

1. Change your variables type `uint8_t` to `int` (for `%d`)
2. Change `%d` to `%2` `SCNu8` (for `uint8_t`)

These solutions should be fixed your problem.
[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/xdhq7bz9h)